# Seeing if an item is directly followed by another item in a list (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, while-loop

I want to check if an item is directly followed by another in a list. My code works sort of, however, say if i want to see if "1" is followed by "3", it won't work if the list goes [1, 1, 3]. I've tried playing around with while loops but haven't really gotten it to work. Here is my code so far:

```
def contains(lst, a, b):
x = 1
y = 0
for _ in lst:
    while (lst.index(a)+y) == (lst.index(a)+x):
        x += 1
        y += 1
    else:
        if lst.index(b) == (lst.index(a) + x):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

My plan is to make a while loop that checks if the item after "a" has the same value as "a", and  when the values are no longer the same, it compares the last value of the loop to the next and checks if it equals "b". Can't quite figure out how to get it to work though.

Comment: You would typically zip a list with itself and test the tuples: `any(a == b for a, b in zip(some_list, some_list[1:]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirements aren't well-defined. For arguments of 1 and 3, should [1, 2, 3] return True? e.g. does the next number need to immediately follow the other one or can it appear later in the list?

Here's my attempt at something that checks if `b` appears immediately after `a`:

```
def contains(lst, a, b):
    # Iterate over all entries in the list
    for i, value in enumerate(lst):
        # Check if this entry matches `a` and is not the final entry
        if value == a and i < len(lst):
            # Check if the next entry matches `b`
            if lst[i+1] == b:
                return True
    return False
```

And if `b` appears anywhere in the list after `a`:

```
def contains(lst, a, b):
    # Iterate over all entries in the list
    for i, ivalue in enumerate(lst):
        # Check if this entry matches `a`
        if ivalue == a and i < len(lst):
            # Now iterate through the rest of the list:
            for jvalue in lst[i+1:]:
                # Check if this entry matches 'b':
                    if jvalue == b:
                        return True
            # Can break this loop after finding first instance of `a`
            break
    return False
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. With "directly" I meant that there cannot be an item between "a" and "b", and that "b" appears immediately after "a". So your first code is correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the option that @MarkMeyer mentioned in the comments you can use regex with a *lookahead assertion*.

```
import re

def contains(data, a, b):
    pattern = re.compile(r"{}(?={})".format(a, b))
    if isinstance(data, list):
        data = "".join(str(s) for s in data)
    maybe_found = pattern.search(data)
    if maybe_found:
        return True
    return False

contains(data, 1, 3)
>> True

contains(data, 1, 4)
>> False

contains(data, 1, 1)
>> True
```